# AngularJS simple app memory leak

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks

I have a problem in my main application, where using the app without refreshing, the memory (and CPU usage) is getting higher.

I managed to reproduce it: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fmgy778r/

```
angular.module('TestModule', []).controller('TestController', function ($controller, $scope) {
    $scope.a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10 * 1000 * 1000; i++)
        $scope.a.push("stringstring" + i);
});
```

Press **shift + ESC** on Chrome.

Now press "**problem**", and your memory for that tab will be 1GB+-.

Press "**default**" and see that the memory is still 1GB.

Press "**problem**" and see that the memory is going down and then up again.

Press "**default**" once, and then press "**problem**" 10 times in a fast click spamy way, and see your memory spiking to 1.5-2GB

I have about 30 modules in my system, and if such thing is happening to all, I see why the memory is just bloating.

Why is this happening?

How can it be fixed?

*I know I should use `this` and not `$scope`, but I wanted to reproduce the real code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want 10000000 items inside an array (and the same amount added per clilck). This seems like a very unusual use case. I would assume that this is not angulars fault since the same happens when you use vanilla Javascript.

Comment: I agree with @DrColossos why you want to loop 10000000 times. the problem is on that part. 
javascript is client side, don't let your client have hard time. :D

Comment: Does this change anything for you: https://jsfiddle.net/fmgy778r/1/ ??

Comment: By this you are creating 10000000 $scope variables, which is very large number for angular's change detection model. As per my understanding angular can handle upto 10000 $scope variables properly. And if you just want 1 $scope variable with these many values then you can go with solution providede by @Fidel90.

Comment: @DrColossos This is really not the point.. there are no 10,000,000 variables in my controllers, lets say, a hundrad per controller sounds modest. The thing is, that after leaving that page, and destroying that scope, the memory is still being used.

Comment: @Fidel90 It does not. When I go back to "default", the memory used by "problem" is still being used.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with the steps you've provided and the jsFiddle I've posted and I can't see any memory consumption over 480MB in Chrome. When I switch from `default` to `problem` it raises to 600-800MB but then immediately falls back to 480MB. Even when I click on `problem` in a "spammy way".

Comment: @Fidel90 Thats odd, I see 1GB. but anyway, it is not normal for it to take 480MB. When you are on "default", it takes nothing, then you go to "problem", it takes alot. What happens when you go back to "default"? for me it stays on 1GB, and does not destroy that scope.

Comment: When I go back from problem to default it still takes 480MB. After the first click on default that's the amount of memory my Chrome wants, no matter if I'm going back to default or clicking on problem like hell... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand now what you want. I tested it with your provided and a newer version (1.4.8 is available in fiddle).

Without modifications, my Chrome (64-bit, Linux, 8GB) uses initial 120MB, after clicking "problem", it goes up to more than 1 GB and stays there.

But if you add

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   $scope.a = [];
});
```

into your first controller, the memory will go back down. Note that this is not immediate but after the next run of the garbage collector (on my machine, this happened after approx. 5 - 15 sec). After the GC ran, the memory goes back to the initial value. Event with many "problem" clicks, the memory stays constant since "$destroy" event is triggered and the variable is reset and ready for the GC.

Comment: Do you know why angular does not "free/delete/unset" all varaibles on destroy, and I need to do it manually? I have no cases like this^ when there is only one variable occupying most of the memory.

Comment: I honestly don't know why this is the case but I assume this is more a JS issue than an angular issue. Maybe angular does destroy its scope vars, but GC takes more time to do its thing and this statement is wrong. Maybe someone with deeper angular experience could answer this. Personally, I always to things like this, even in smaller Controllers, Directives, .... Beside, it is best practice to implement such lifecycle methods that do all the clean up.